# Ext Js 4.2 Using ext-all.js instead of ext-debug.js in my index.jsp breaks my application

Tags: extjs4.2

Using anything but the ext-debug.js file in my index.jsp is breaking my Ext Js 4.2 application.

I don't understand why this is happening, because, as I read, the ext-all.js file should be used on the production version of my application. It contains the whole framework in a single compressed file, so it should be faster.

So what I do is this: I create the app.jsb3 file, then the app-all.js file (using Sencha Tools 2.0 commands), then I edit the index.jsp file and change from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-debug.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script>
```

Then I start the application and I got an error, although running it before the change works fine.
I also tried with ext-debug-all.js and ext.js, every time I get a distinct error.
Did anyone have this kind of issue?

Thanks in advance for your answers.
This is my index.jsp file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="extjs/resources/css/ext-all-neptune.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/desktop.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/nc-custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/modules.css" />
<!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-all.js"></script> -->
<!--     <script type="text/javascript" src="extjs/ext-theme-neptune.js"></script> -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please could you give more details on how it breaks your application ? what errors you get ?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But does it matter? I mean the two files should contain the same thing, right? Anyway, the error appears in a file I use to customize a grid, and it sounds something like: Cannot run getAction of undefined. But how come this is working using ext-debug.js?

Comment: The problem is obviously elsewhere, perhaps your ext-all.js altered in some ways, the error might give a hint.

Comment: Could give some advice, what should I do?

Comment: i really lack the necessary info to point you to some direction, please provide the <head></head> of the page you having an error in, and try showing the error (from the javascript console).

Comment: Also I'm getting some warnings like "[Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'app.module.tools.ToolsModule'; consider adding Ext.require('app.module.tools.ToolsModule') above Ext.onReady " on some stores, maybe this will help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those 2 files are not the same. `ext-debug-all.js = ext-all.js`, and `ext.js = ext-debug.js`.  The `all` files contain the entire framework, whereas the other files contain the **core** files needed by the framework.  Those files should be used if you are doing the full build using Sencha Command, and your `requires` and `uses` directives are all correct.

If you are creating the `app-all.js` file like you say, then you should not need to include *any* Ext files in your jsp.  The `app.all` will have the entire body of js that you need, including the required ExtJS framework files.

Comment: I edited the above code and added the content of the index.jsp file. I commented the 2 lines as I understood from your explanations. When I start the application I get Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined in the app-all.js. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: How are you building app-all.js?

Comment: Using the Sencha Tools 2.0 commands:     $ cd C:\pathtoapp...\webapp NEWLINE
$ sencha create jsb -a http://localhost/dologin -p app.jsb3 NEWLINE
$ sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .

Comment: Don't think I'll be able to debug what is happening from afar, but you should really consider upgrading to a newer version of Sencha Command.  They have made essential improvements in the past year+ since v2.0.

Comment: It is impossible for me to upgrade, it's a huge application, very customized, so the only way is to use Sencha Tools 2.0, and I am not allowed to change anything, just have to create the production file. Thanks for your help, anyway.